# xpath with anchor tag and sibbling text

Tags: automated-testing

Need to get xpath for the following. It is not accpeting with anchor tag as I have several anchor tags with same random auto generated ID.

The only difference I can pull with is text. How do I get that

```
.//tr[@class='r ng-scope']/td[contains(@class,'v3details')]/a[contains(@id,'anchor')]
```

[image]

[image]

Sample HTML:

```
<tr class="r ng-scope" ng-repeat-start="category in resultSection.content.category" ng-init="randNum2=resultsCtrl.getRandom(); "> 
    <td class="v3details_td_text1_b0110" style="padding: 5px 30px;" colspan="2" width="100%"> 
        <a id="anchor__" class="v3_links ng-binding" style="text-decoration: none;" href="" ng-click="resultsCtrl.setSwapThisTextLink(randNum1,randNum2)"> 
            <span id="icon_res_det_catg_b1967e0b2482995_651b54721c2b232"> 
                <img src="images/spacer.gif" height="1" width="6"/> 
            </span>
            DeviceInfo 
        </a> 
    </td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: It looks like you mistyped the HTML you added - I took a guess at where the inner span was supposed to end but as typed it was malformed.

Comment: No, I copy pasted the code as it is, IT has Span tag and outside span there is Text DeviceInfo.

Answer (score 1):

If you have text of anchor than you should try 
//a[contains(text(),'Add New Button']

or findElement(By.partialLinkText("partialLinkText"))

Comment: Something like this should work. I'd recommend asking the developers to better decorate elements for testing though